# Assign same queue item to multiple workers

Tags: algorithm, queue, language-agnostic, computer-science, worker

We have a logical queue of tasks, where each task has to be assigned to multiple workers.
The numbers of workers to be assigned are based on a configuration of Minimum and Maximum workers.
A worker should not see the same task that they have already completed. It is not necessary that all workers will see all the tasks.

Total number of workers can change dynamically. Each worker can become online or offline anytime.

Each worker can choose to either complete the task or let it expire.
On expiry the task should be assigned to any worker who has not already completed the task.

Is there a good algorithm to solve this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

### The easy solution:

Greedily assign tasks:

- For every task that is ready.
- Find the Minimum <= N <= Maximum workers that
  didn't see the task yet and assign them.
- Repeat until you either run
  out of workers or finish all the tasks.
- If a worker comes online or finishes task, re-check for all the tasks.
- If a new task comes, re-check for the available workers.

This solution might be enough if there are not that many tasks, as it is computation heavy and recomputes everything.

### The possible optimizations:

If the greedy solution fails(and it probably will), there are ways to improve on it. I will try to list those that come to my mind but it won't be an exhaustive list.

First, my personal favorite: **Network flows**. Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to resolve the minimal number of workers requirement, however it would be fast and it would result in a maximum possible workers being assigned at any given moment.

- Create the network Source - Workers - Tasks - Sink. Edges workers to tasks will be linked and unlinked as needed:
- when a worker is available for a task, create the edge with weight 1, otherwise don't create the edge.
- From source link an edge with weight one to each online worker.
- From every task link an edge with weight equal to its maximal worker capacity.

You could even differentiate between different kinds of workers, network flows are awesome. The algorithms are fast which makes them suitable even for large graphs. Also they are available in many libraries so you won't have to implement them yourself. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to enforce the minimal workers rule. At least I don't see one right now, there might be some way. Or maybe at least a heuristic

Second, **be smart while being greedy**:

- Create a queue for every task.
- When a worker is available, register him for every task he can do into its queue.
- When a worker is not available, remove him from the queues.
- When a task has enough workers, start progress and disable these workers.

This is still the brute force approach however since you keep the queues, you limit the amount of the necessary computation to a reasonable level. The potential downside is that large tasks(with a large minimal number of workers) might be stalled by the small tasks that will be easier to start - and will eat up the workers. So there will probably be some further checking/balancing and prioritizing needed.

There is definitely more to be tried &  done for your task at hand, however the information you provided is rather limited so this advice is not that specific.